# getting an arror 500 when trying to register new user

Tags: node.js, reactjs

im completing a fullstack project using react and node
when trying to register a user or a product i keep on getting error 500 in the browser and this error in my visual studio terminal:
Error: Illegal arguments: string, object

here's my create user function:

```
const createUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userExist = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (userExist) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already exists");
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid user data");
  }
});
```

what could cause an error 500?

trying to register a new user to the db

Comment: _what could cause an error 500?_ any unhandled error in your back end code. To solve a 500 you need to debug your back end code and find the unhandled exception. You need to post the node code behind whichever web call generated the 500.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can follow some steps:

1. Try to console the data from the request parameters i.e name, email, password and manipulate your request parameters
2. Else use:- const email=req.body.email; such syntax for all the request params
3. Again try to console the req params, hope this time these params will be there.

Use this modification:

```
const createUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const userExist = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (userExist) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already exists");
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid user data");
  }
});
```

if your req params are not accessing the body params from the form, try using body-parser or multer for the same.

Note: Try using console.log() to know the line of concern of your code.